# Explicit SQL result set with multiple rows

Tags: sql

How can I create an SQL result set that contains multiple rows which I want to specify explicitly (e.g., using a `select` statement without a `from` clause). I can only think of the following, but wonder if there is a shorter way.

```
select 2 union all select 3 union all select 5 union all select 7;
```

Result (in PostgreSQL):

```
 ?column?
----------
        2
        3
        5
        7
```

Comment: If your SQL implementable supports [Recursive CTE](https://www.essentialsql.com/recursive-cte/) - you can use it.

Comment: Is something preventing your from creating a bona fide table with these values?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using VALUES keyword. Here is an example

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES(1), (2), (3)) as t(value);
```

Comment: Ahh, just `VALUES (1), (2), (3);` seems to do the trick. Many thanks!